# Want to give different bar color for each series using custom colors

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, ngx-charts

Is it possible to add different color for each series. using customColors? for

```
customColors() {
result = JSON.parse('[{"name":"Used","value":"#e8c728"},{"name":"Used","value":"#FF0000"}]');
return result;
}
```

Sample Chart:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-grouped-vertical-bar-chart?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts
https://stackblitz.com/edit/swimlane-grouped-vertical-bar-chart-cn1o4k

[image]

```
data: [
{
"name": "Lineage Transformations",
"series": [
{
"name": "Limit",
"value": 0
},
{
"name": "Used",
"value": 0
}
]
},
{
"name": "Data sources",
"series": [
{
"name": "Limit",
"value": 10
},
{
"name": "Used",
"value": 0
}
]
}
]
```

Comment: It appears: At least not without writing a custom chart, but that might even be probelmatic...

Comment: Any suggestion possible..